# Android ListView with headers and swipes

Tags: android, listview

I am working on a shopping list app, and in one activity I need show many shopping list that I want use expandable/collapsible headers. Also, I want to strike out item by left swipe and delete item by right swipe.

I am looking for some `ListView` that can do this.

I tried to use `StickyListHeaders` lib with swipe layout but it works incorrectly (white spaces after deleting).

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to update your adapter content and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh your data and remove the empty space.